# Ожидание окончания setInterval()

Tags: javascript

В общем, задача такая: 
Нужно из расширения под хром забрать данные в письме яндекс почты. 
Письма подгружаются динамически, страница не перезагружается.

Для начала отлавливаю onhashchange, далее, пытаюсь напрямую поймать данные из элементов. НО, поскольку данные еще не догрузились, их, соответственно, нет.

Попытки обернуть это в `$(document).ready()` результатов не дали.
Удалось добиться получения значений блоков только  с помощью ожидания, и проверки наличия данных в переменных:

```
window.onhashchange = function(){
var awaw = setInterval(function(){
                e = $('.mail-Message-Sender-Email.mail-ui-HoverLink-Content').text();
                s = $('.mail-User.mail-User_small.js-contact-actions-dropdown.js-email').attr('data-email');
                if ((e !== undefined) && (s !== undefined)){
                    console.log('E '+e+' S '+s);
                    clearInterval(a);
                    return {"e":e, "s":s};
                }
            },500);
            e = awaw.e;
            s= awaw.s;
            console.log('EE '+e+' SS '+s);
}
```

НО, теперь в итоге, код исполняется параллельно с setInterval. Т.е. - интервал продолжает крутиться и дальше, но и код после него исполняется. В общем и целом выходит, что весь код ниже оперирует с пустыми переменными, не приводя ни к какому результату.

Какие могут быть варианты побороть это дело?
Т.е. что бы код после интервала исполнялся после его остановки?

Comment: setInterval - никогда не заканчивается, он потому и интервал, что крутится бесконечно

Comment: Есть `clearInterval(awaw)`

Почитать можно [здесь](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_clearinterval.asp)